# git merge a branch that has two working directory in it

Tags: git

In my project I have two branch: `dev-backend` and `dev-frontend`. I have another branch `dev`. in `dev` I add two worktree of frontend and backend branch using `git worktree add backend dev-backend` and `git worktree add frontend dev-frontend`. now I want to merge `dev-backend` and `dev-frontend` into `main`.

How can I do it?

my branches:

```
git branch:
* dev
+ dev-backend
+ dev-frontend
  main
```

in branch `dev` there are two directory: `backend` and `frontend` that is related to their branches.

```
ls -a
.  ..  .git  .gitignore  .prettierrc  backend  frontend  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json
```

Comment: `git worktree add` doesn't change anything here. It just gives you a place where you can have a different commit checked out.

Answer (score 0):

First checkout to `main`

`git co main`

Then merge the two branches:

```
git merge dev-backend
git merge dev-frontend
```